# "@" sign in startup commands

Tags: scripts, lxde, autostart

In my `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` file I have lines like:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
```

Other lines (that I added using the Preferences/Default Applications for LX Session/Autostart menu) are not prefaced with the `@`.

What does the `@` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [LXDE Lxsession](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDE#Lxsession):

> Each line in ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart represents a command to be executed. If a line starts with @, and the command following it crashes, the command is automatically re-executed.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  And thanks for the reference too.

Comment: @AndroidDev And from Meta Stack Exchange: There is nothing inherently wrong with writing "Thank you" in a comment.   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment